# adb restore time

Tags: adb, restore

I want to use the `adb restore` . I use `adb restore` to restore a backup. But my problem after some delay if i don't click  ok, the mechanism restore stops. I want my restore do not stop. And if possible it starts automatically and it does not expect a validation for me. used adb back up to get my backup.ab. Then i use `adb restore backup.ab`

Answer (score 1):

You will always have to approve on the device when initiating an `adb backup` or `adb restore` -- this is a security measure. Otherwise any villain could obtain your data (`adb backup`) or place malware on your device (`adb restore`).

If you don't approve the action on your device, it is assumed it could be mentioned villain intending some evil actions, and hence the process is aborted -- again said security measure.

To my knowledge, there isn't anything (apart from applying some hack to the `adb` code/libraries/binaries on the device itself) to "work around" this.